# logstash and kafka and graylog and order of messages

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, logstash, graylog3

We have an application with the `event log`, our application send `event log` to `Kafka` with `JSON format`. our `topic` in Kafka `has one partition` because we need to read `order message`, also we use `Logstash` for consuming `event log` and convert `JSON` format to `GELF` format then send to `Graylog`.
our problem is considering that the topic has a partition, but the consumer`(Logstash)` does not read the messages in order and our order is disturbed. we use

```
 stdout{ codec => rubydebug }
```

in output `Logstash` config and this `Logstash` log confirms the issue, Naturally, we don't have events in GaryLag in order.
Why the order is messed up. Problems with Kafka or `Logstash` or `Graylog` or ...?

thanks.

*UPDATE*

logstash config:

```
input {
  kafka {
        bootstrap_servers => "kafka1:9092,kafka2:9092,kafka3:9092"
        group_id => "MyTopicReader"
        topics => "MyTopic"
        consumer_threads => 1
        enable_metric => "false"
        auto_offset_reset => "latest"
 }
}

filter {
   json {
     source => "message"
  }
}

output {
      gelf {

           host => "ip-graylog"
           port => 12201
           sender => "ip-logstash"

    }
 stdout{ codec => rubydebug }
}
```

pipline config `pipelines.yml`:

```
- pipeline.id: main
  path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/*.conf"
```

Pipeline Settings in `logstash.yml`

```
pipeline.id: main
pipeline.workers: 2
pipeline.batch.size: 125
pipeline.batch.delay: 50
```

Comment: What is your full pipeline config? How many workers are you using? Per default logstash set the number of workers equal to the number of cpu cores, if you have 4 cores you will have 4 workers, which means that you will have 4 threads for your filters and outputs.

Comment: @leandrojmp please look at the updates`(logstash config)`

Comment: @pyramid13 were you able to solve this issue? i have similar one.

Comment: @Jags Which version of the Graylog do you use?

Comment: @pyramid13 I don't use Graylog. I have kafka->logstash->elastic search. But having same ordering issue. Found documentation at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/processing.html. Seems like akhilesh-bhardwaj answer will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Start Logstash with `-w 1` to run a single pipeline worker.